# How to share Link to Facebook with image from external memory?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to share a link to facebook like this:

```
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                .setContentDescription("some text")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://some website"))
                .build();

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);  // Show facebook ShareDialog
    }
```

but it doesn't even show the dialog shareDialog. but when i set the ImageUrl like:

```
.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.dropbox.com/myfolder/apple.png"))
```

it works fine.

how can i share a link to Facebook with image from the device storage?

Comment: It's should work, Make sure image is exist and public access

Comment: no it's not when i change the '.setImageUrl(Uri.parse())' to the imageuri from device storage. the sharedialog doesn't even showup?

Comment: it's should work, try with thumbnail image

Comment: i'm currently testing it on emulator is there any possibility that the app isn't working because of that?

Comment: May be, try in real device...

Comment: no it's not working on the device either